# Kurento Media Server is running but unable to connect kurento media server websocket

Tags: websocket, webrtc, ubuntu-16.04, kurento

I have installed latest stable version of **Kurento Media Server(KMS)** on local machine with specification **Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial** following [this documentation](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installation.html#local-installation). I have verified everything and it is working fine and getting same traces as mentioned in this [documentation](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installation.html#check-your-installation). But when I tried to connect KMS via websocket

> ws://localhost:8888/kurento

I'm getting connection time out issue. This is not particular to port 8888 only, any port assigned to KMS, leads to connection timeout.

Getting request timeout issue although every other application on same machine is telneted and getting response expectedly but it is not true when I run below command.

> sudo telnet 127.0.0.1:8888

I also tried to reach out websocket connection via [Smart WEB Socket](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smart-websocket-client/omalebghpgejjiaoknljcfmglgbpocdp) but getting connection time out issue.

Comment: What's the status of your UFW? Even I am encountering this problem when my UFW is enabled.

Comment: @aashu UFW is also enabled.

Comment: that's what I am facing, I tried to dig up more, have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557856/ufw-not-allowing-kurento-media-server-6-7-to-get-connected-through-ws-uri

Comment: I found a (temporary) solution, you may check it on the above link

Comment: after kms installation , Which demo  project did you used for web.
Many projects are there by using java , noje.js .

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing with the KMS tutorials or your own application?

If its your own application the websocket connection timeout issue maybe unrelated to Kurento Media Server(KMS). A websocket connection timeout issue is a abnormal closure which tends to occur when a websocket is detected to be idle.

To maintain the websocket connection it is usually suggested to implement a heartbeat. Below are a couple of posts which discuss the matter a bit more:

[Must websockets have heartbeats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111656/must-websockets-have-heartbeats)

[Sending websocket ping/pong frame from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585355/sending-websocket-ping-pong-frame-from-browser)

Comment: I'm testing with the KMS tutorials.